# How to verify adhar number using android app

Tags: android

I have a requirement to validate users adhar card number.

So i want to integrate that on my android app. Is it possible ? If yes, then how ?

Please help me.

Comment: Yes. There is a SDK https://aadhaarapi.com/android-sdk-integration/

Comment: but sir, i want SDK file (.aar format). how can i find this. On this link have written that i have to drop a mail on contact@aadhaarapi.com and i have already done it. But they are not responding me.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the security reason Central Government of india is decided to give the Permissions to Authenticate Person details using uid to only Authorized Banking Institutions .UID Verification API's are available to only authorized Companys..!

Comment: so here is no any way to access their api.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check aadhar number existing in database or not then for that need official API and license from UIDAI. But you want to just validate like gmail an phone number then you can go with **Verhoeff's algorithm**. This algorithm used by UIDAI for generate unique aadhar number.

here are the [link](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm) for code example. I hope it's help you to validate aadhar.

Comment: no sir. my requirement is that on the basis of that adhar number which person will enter, i will send an otp on their mobile number which attached with their adhar number. So i want an api or like this type of thing , which will help me

Comment: @YogeshSharma then there are no any official Public API from UIDAI to access aadhar information or send OTP. You need to go with this one : https://aadhaarapi.com/android-sdk-integration/

OR

You need to take license from UIDAI.